# Update TextBox text when a ComboBox's value is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

**My app:** A Store has a Products collection and an int Id property. A Product has string ProductCode and Description properties. A ViewModel references a single instance of Store. ViewModel has a static collection of Products (ProductList). My View's DataContext is set to ViewModel. My View displays Store via the ViewModel.

**What works:** My View has a TextBlock bound to Store's Id.

**What doesn't work:** My View has a DataGrid for adding Products to Store's Products collection. The DataGrid for adding Products to Store's Products collection allows me to choose a new ProductCode, using a DataGridComboBoxColumn column. This works fine. However, I want my chosen ProductCode to update the DataGridTextBoxColumn which is bound to a Product's Description.

I've spent hours searching the net and I haven't found anything that quite matches my scenario, except maybe "Example 12" from this link, but I haven't gotten it to work for my project: [Best ComboBox Tutorial Ever](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19493.wpf-best-combobox-tutorial-ever.aspx)

## Solved:

#### The most significant change to my code is a RefreshDescription method that fires after ProductCode is set for a Product. This method takes ProductCode as an argument and queries a static ProductList to find the first matching Description. The user can change the auto-populated Description property if desired.

Code snippet from my view:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Store.Id}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Store.Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                Header="ProductCode"
                ItemsSource="{x:Static m:ItemsProvider.ProductList}" 
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProductCode,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                SelectedValuePath="ProductCode"
                DisplayMemberPath="ProductCode"/>
        <!-- 
        I want Description for my chosen Product to pop in automatically... but how? 
        -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : NotifyObject
{
    // Constructor
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _store = new Store() { Id = 1 };
    }
    
    // Fields
    Store _store;
    Product _selectedProduct;
    
    // Properties
    public Store Store {
        get { return _store; }
        set {
            _store = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Commission");
        }
    }   
}
```

My Product model:

```
public class Product : NotifyObject
{
    // Constructor
    public Product() { }
    
    // Fields
    string _productCode;
    string _description;
    
    // Properties
    public string ProductCode { 
        get { return _productCode; }
        set {
            _productCode = value;       
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCode");
            RefreshDescription(ProductCode);
        }
    }
    
    public string Description {
        get { return _description; }
        set {
            _description = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
    
   // Private Methods
    void RefreshDescription(string productCode)
    {
        if (ItemsProvider.ProductList.Count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Product product = ItemsProvider.ProductList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductCode == productCode);
        this.Description = (product == null ? "" : product.Description);
    }
}
```

My Store model:

```
public class Store : NotifyObject
{
    // Constructor
    public Store()
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    }
    
    // Fields
    int _id;
    
    // Properties       
    public int Id { 
        get { return _id; }
        set {
            _id = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }     
}
```

My static class for getting a list of products to choose from:

```
public static class ItemsProvider
{
    static ObservableCollection<Product> _productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    static ItemsProvider() 
    {
        _productList = new ObservableCollection<Product>() {
            new Product() { ProductCode = "111", Description = "a" },
            new Product() { ProductCode = "222", Description = "b" },
            new Product() { ProductCode = "333", Description = "c" },
            new Product() { ProductCode = "444", Description = "d" }                    
        };
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList {
        get {
            return _productList;
        }           
    }           
}
```

Comment: any possible way you can post a screenshot of what you're explaining?

Comment: When assigning ProductCode, by changing it in Combobox, make it refresh description. Of courde Product class needs to implement InotifyPropertyChanged in order to any change could be reflected in DataGrid since ObservableCollection cannot make it.

Comment: @Maximus you are correct; that's what I want to accomplish. The Product class implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Kind of funny, I just explained what to do. When you use Combobox in order to change property ProductCode you need to have Description refreshed. In implementation of ProducCode add code making it, forcing to change Description value depending on ProdutCode value. When you change it then InotifyPropertyChanged will let DataGrid know about changes, if only you applied notification for Desctiption.

Comment: typo? public Store Store {
        get { return _store; }
        set {
            _store = value;
            **NotifyPropertyChanged("Store");**
        }  Also have you implemented NotifyPropertyChanged on all Product properties?

Comment: ObservableCollection by default notifies when you add/remove item but not about any change in properties of object it stores. You do not have to on all just for Description in order to refresh value in DataGrid.

Comment: @Maximus "In implementation of ProducCode add code making it, forcing to change Description value depending on ProdutCode value." <-- This is my problem... not knowing what to code for this to happen. But I may have just figured it out. When ProductCode is set, I can set Description from my ViewModel code. Let me try and post my code.

Comment: @Stian , no typo. Here's the code for NotifyObject, which each model/entity inherits: ` public abstract class NotifyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {   
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  
  public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
   if (PropertyChanged != null) {
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: call it when you set Description, public string Description {set { if(description != value) { description = value; PropertyChanged(...)}}

Comment: @Maximus not any better, unfortunately. I'm trying to call a method after ProductCode property is set to then set the Description property, but it's creating a circular reference. I just added my Product model code to my question so you can look at it (how it was before I've been trying to insert a "description refresh method").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my edited question:

> The most significant change to my code is a RefreshDescription method that fires after ProductCode is set for a Product. This method takes ProductCode as an argument and queries a static ProductList to find the first matching Description. The user can change the auto-populated Description property if desired.

Thank you again for those who helped me to come to this conclusion!

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of doing this is to raise `PropertyChanged` when the product code changes, and then do a lookup to get the description:

```
// Properties
public string ProductCode { 
    get { return _productCode; }
    set {
        _productCode = value;       
        base.NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductCode");
        base.NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
    }
}

public string Description {
    get { 
        var matchingProduct = ViewModel.ProductList.FirstOrDefault(product => product.ProductCode == ProductCode);
        return (matchingProduct == null ? "" : matchingProduct.Description);
    }
}
```

Probably a better approach to the above would be to define a different class for your ProductList and Products collections.  The former should be *ProductType* (containing the product code and description), and the latter should be *ProductInstance* (containing just the product code).  Then you could use something like the above to define the read-only product description on the latter class.

Comment: I think I have it figured out. You're on the right track, but this doesn't work perfect because I need to let the user key in a different Description if she desires. I'll post my solution tomorrow - gotta head home for the day. Thank you McGarnagle and @Maximus!

Comment: Thank you @McGarnagle and Maximus for your contributions! I upvoted your answer and comment. Please see my comments under "Solved" in my question. The only thing lacking from McGarnagle's answer is a setter for Description; I don't want to remove the user's ability to change Description to something other than the auto-populated value if she desires.